# What does javascript function window.show() return

Tags: javascript, window

In the following code what is returned and stored in var `poppedWin`

```
var poppedWin =  window.show();
```

Can I use this var `poppedWin` to detect `window.hide()` or `window.close()` event?

Comment: What language or context?

Comment: You need to provide more details, a browser `window` does not implement a `show()` (unless one has been added by something)

Comment: Got it sir. Solved the problem myself. Thanks.